# Permission to access another remote server Linux, Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix, centos

How can I allow a remote server to run a command without asking for password and any confirmation.

I use this command but it asks for password,

```
ssh root@0.0.0.0 /var/workingproject/notify
```

is there a way I can whitelist a remote server to access my server and execute a command without asking for password?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can add your public key, generally found on your local box at `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` to your remote server's authorized keys file.  To do it automatically, you could use something like this:

```
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub root@0.0.0.0
```

Or alternatively, you can open the remote authorized keys file (~/.ssh/authorized_keys) and add your public key directly.

If you do not have a public key configured on your local instance, you can run:

```
ssh-keygen
```

to create one.